Parsing and Playing AMC/ASF in Unity
I've been trying to manually parse and play amc/asf files in unity. I've parsed the data but I'm not applying it correctly.
Here is my setup:

Parsing the data
It is assumed that Unity uses a left-hand system (X right, Y up, Z forward) and AMC/ASF uses a right-hand system (X left, Y up, Z forward). After parsing the values but before caching them, the following operations are performed:


For positional/ directional vectors: x -> -x e.g. direction = (-3, 2, -1) -> (3, 2, -1)
For Eulers: z -> -z e.g. axis = (15, 0, 20) -> (15, 0, -20)

The component that stores parsed asf data on each joint
The container for the parsed frame information

Making sure Eulers are converted to quaternions in the correct order
This function creates a quaternion from an Euler with a specified rotation order
Here I have two variants but I am not sure which is correct. Say I am given axis 0 30 -20 XYZ in the asf file. Would the corresponding axis quaternion be qx * qy * qz or qz * qy * qx?

Initialising the rig
First, :hierarchy is parsed to generate the GameObjects with the JointASF component attached:
Parsing hierarchy


Second, bonedata is parsed to instantiate the initial pose and cache the joint specific asf information:
Parsing bonedata
Here I am not entirely sure if the way the joint positions and orientations are being set appropriately? Is axis being used appropriately?
The resulting rig in unity looks like this:
Highlighting rfemur

Finally, applying the Eulers found in AMC to the rig
I've been experimenting with several ways of applying the AMC Eulers, none of which are producing the desired result:
Cycling through different methods after the animation clips is finished

I have read all of the documentation on ASF and AMC and tried to apply my interpretations of them but none seem to work. I was hoping someone could at what step(s) I am doing something wrong.
